# Finding a framework for real-time cross browser mobile app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, real-time

I'm trying to build a mobile (iPhone & Android) HTML 5 app that will be heavily real time oriented.  I will be using Socket.IO and Node.js as an accessor for my real time data.  I've read/tried alot out there, so here is my current feeling about the products I've tried

1. JQuery Mobile- **Pros:** ease of use, no learning curve **Cons:** No support for real-time, not very "Native" feeling
2. Sencha Touch- **Pros:** Easy to create native looking UI, easy integration to real-time js stuff **Cons:** Extremely poor documentation

These are the two I've tried.  I'd love to use Sencha touch, but every problem I run into takes days of trial and error (and SO posts) to get through, I just can't waste the time.  Anyone know of either a way I can use JQuery to do real time stuff, or just a better framework?

## Edit

I did not make clear, there are 2 aspects to what I'm looking for: real-time aspects, but also some UI framework as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery/jQMobile in combination with [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), and [Backbone.iobind.js](http://alogicalparadox.com/backbone.iobind/) to do real-time updating via socket.io

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/), [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/) and [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). That's what I would use.